# Correct syntax/status for searching an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, range

Here is what I think should happen, but it isn't.  And I have a feeling it's because I do not open or activate the Worksheet... On_Click, I create a new workbook, ** this is where I may need to open the workbook to search ** , If I find a match for "FLOATP", it copies row, and writes to new workbook.  This works perfect if I'm searching an active workbook.... But not something on my desktop (not active/open).

I've put together a program that opens a closed wb, does task and then closes wb... But I'm not sure I can get it to work with code I have..  Thoughts?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



Dim cell As Range

Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:="test42"



   For Each cell In Workbooks("[C:\Users\32768\Desktop\2019oseDist.xlsb]").Range("EI2:EI60000")



      If InStr(cell.Value, "FLOATP") > 0 Then



        MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name

        cell.EntireRow.Copy

        ActiveSheet.Range("A25").End(xlUp).Select

        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste



     End If



   Next cell



End Sub
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to do. Maybe you should provide a step by step description in pseudo-code like (1) open workbook named ... (2) loop all cells in Range xy on Sheet z on that workbook and so on. BTW: the code you posted fails in line 3 because `Workbooks` has no `Range` object - you should state something like `Workbooks(strMyWorkbookName).Sheets(strSheetName).Range(...)`

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you try to achieve first, then explain how you have tried to achieve it and finally ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from a closed workbook. But your code tries to loop through thousands of rows, meaning thousands of reads. That isn't efficient.

Look at a column of cells as an array. When you loop through the cells you are using the array Excel has created. If you copy those cells to an array you set up yourself you don't need to access Excel's array. The point is that each access to Excel's array is slow and each access to your own is fast. But copying one of Excel's arrays into one of your own is a single access and also very fast.

That leads to the idea to access the closed workbook only once, to extract a huge array and copy it into one you set up in your own code. You can do your looping efficiently without further referencing the source.

Once you find "FLOATP" you might either access the closed workbook again to extract another range, this time the row you can now identify. Or you might have taken the entire sheet in the first read. The sheer volume of data you load into an array doesn't need to bother you in itself. But you may wish to run comparative speed tests.

Also consider what you need to extract. Copied arrays are fast because they contain values only. If you need to get formats as well from the closed source copying takes on a different meaning. I wouldn't recommend copying many thousands of different cells into an array of cells - the entire worksheet, in fact. You probably don't need formatting for the initial search but you should consider using the `Find` method in place of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Really appreciate the time you spent to explain. I will spend a couple of days and see what I come up with. Contractor provides 160+ columns, which I should be able to reduce to 25ish.  Thanks again! W Pride